# Assembly Language Random Number Generator

Tags: assembly, random, x86, numbers, prng

I have recently started to learn assembly language. For a project I am working on I have to make a random number generator using linear congruence. I am suppose to take in three numbers. An upper bound, a lower bound and a number of how many random numbers I want. As for the formula for getting a random number I came up with....

randomNumber = (seed % (upper-lower) + lower)

I then tried to put this into code. 
I came up with this

```
.data
  upper BYTE 100      ;setting upper limit 100
  lower BYTE 0        ;setting lower limit 0
  number BYTE 5       ;number of random numbers

.code
call main
exit

main proc

   cls    
   mov bx,upper            ;moving upper bound into bx
   mov dx,lower            ;moving lower bound into dx
   mov ax,2914017          ;taking a random number for this trial
   mov ecx,number          ;setting the loop counter
L1:
   sub bx,dx               ;(upper-lower)
   div bx               
   add ah,dx               ;(randomNumber mod (bx) + lower

main endp
```

I am curious how I would print out the random number at the end of each loop cycle. And if the above code makes any sense.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If this is on Windows then some suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922134/printing-out-a-number-in-assembly-language

Comment: Printing is highly platform specific. Where are you trying to assemble and execute this? MS-DOS? Windows? Linux? Also, This instruction won't fly: "mov ax,2914017"-- ax is a 16-bit register which maxes out at 65535. eax is 32 bits, however.

Comment: This is all kinds of wrong.  Most importantly, that expression doesn't produce a new seed.  Usually you need to multiply and add some well-chosen constants before you modulo.  Second, `div bx` divides `dx:ax` by `bx`, but you didn't zero `dx`.  Load `lower` into `esi` or `edi`.  (And do it with `movzx`, because they memory locations are bytes.  You're loading them with word loads, so `mov dx, [lower]` will put `0x500` into `dx`.)

Comment: It should be relatively straight forward to implement the one discussed here: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/random_number.png

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is platform dependent, so you need to specifiy this, and we can help you in a more specific way.

But a common method in real-address-mode (e.g. MS-DOS) is to call an interrupt and send the data to the SO (Standard Output).

Example (the %macro keywords are preprocessor directives that NASM understands - but not all compilers use it, but I included it for clarity):

```
%macro printLn 1
        mov ah, 09h ; 9h means "write a string" on screen
        mov edx, %1
        int 21h ; call the ISR for MS-DOS Services
%endmacro        

[SECTION .text]

mystart:
        printLn string
        ret

[SECTION .data]
string  db      "This is a string of text", 13, 10, '$'
```

Another method might be to hook directly a C-Lib function and output that way.

You should refer to [the ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for character codes.

Also remember, as drhirsch mentioned below, that if you intend to output integers, you will need to convert those values into a form that your ISR can handle, like hex equivalents. You will then need to write an additional function to "translate" the values. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031831/outputting-integers-in-assembly-on-linux) is a good example of what I am referring to.

Comment: `int 01fh`? Are you sure you didn't mean `int 21h`?

Comment: You need to convert the number into ASCII before printing