# Simple assembly function wont work

Tags: assembly, operating-system

I can't get the following code to run. It compiles but just gives a blank output. Im trying to take the value of HEX_OUT, remove the trailing zero and then and it with the value of register dx so that the value of HEX_OUT is now the value of dx. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Ash

```
; prints the value of DX as hex.
print_hex:
pusha

mov ax, HEX_OUT     ; ax = 0x00000
shr ax, 1       ; remove trailing 0
and ax, dx      ; and registers and store in ax

        ; TODO :manipulate chars at HEX_OUT to reflect DX

mov bx, ax          ; print the string pointed to      
call print_string   ; by BX

popa
ret

; global variables
HEX_OUT : db '0x0000',0
```

Comment: What error messages are you getting? What assembler are you using? Where is `print_string` defined?

Comment: Print string is defined in another .asm file, both are part of a 'master' file. It all compiles without error using nasm but when you run it, its just giving blank output

Comment: also, if i comment out the shr line and the and line, it displays 0x0000 ....so its got to be something to do with those two lines

Comment: Think about what you're doing in those lines. `mov ax,HEX_OUT` is putting the *address* of your string `0x0000` into `ax`. With the `shr` and `and` commented out, the next thing that happens is the string pointed to by `ax` is printed using `print_string`. If you uncomment those lines, you are taking the address of `0x0000` in `ax` and manipulating it (dividing by 2 and `and`-ing who-knows-what that's in `dx` with it) and getting some new address which points to... what? Who knows, but it's probably not good. You're manipulating the address in this case, not the value.

Answer (score 0):

`HEX_OUT` is not a binary number; it is the address of a *string* (that just happens to be a hexadecimal representation of a number). `shr ax,1` does not manipulate strings; it does not shift characters. It manipulates binary numbers; it shifts *bits*.

The easiest way out is to avoid strings altogether:

```
HEX_OUT: dw 0000h    ; or whatever number you like
```

I hope you have a function like `print_number` at your disposal:

```
mov bx, ax           ; or whatever register is the input for that function
call print_number    ; or whatever is the name of that function
```

Because otherwise you'll have to write (or [find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18879672/printing-hex-values-in-x86-assembly)) code to convert a binary number to its hexadecimal string representation, so that you can feed that to `print_string`.