# Write and run a program that adds 5 bytes of data and saves the result

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dos, masm

Write and run a program that adds 5 bytes of data and saves the result. The data should be the following hex numbers: 25, 12, 15, IF, and 2B. Show the program and the snapshot of the output. The beginning of the program is given:

```
.MODEL SMALL  
.STACK 0100h  
.DATA  
DATA_IN DB 25H, 12H, 15H, 1FH, 2BH 
sum db?
```

I'm not able to get the output in hexadecimal. I have tried this code but still cant get the output I want:

```
.model small

.stack 100h
.data
data_in db 25H, 12H, 15H, 1FH, 2BH 
sum db ?
msg1    db 'The result is : $' ;

.code
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

lea si,data_in
mov al,[si]
mov cx, 4

again:
inc si
add al, [si]
loop again
mov sum,al


lea dx, msg1
mov ah,09h
int 21h
mov ah, 2
mov dl, SUM
int 21h

mov ah,4ch ; end operation
int 21h
end
```

Comment: `sum` has the value `25H+12H+15H+1FH+2BH=96H=150`. When you write this character with [INT21h/AH=2](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2554.htm), it will be displayed as character **û** (depending on current console font). When you want **96** instead, it needs [conversion to hexadecimal string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18879672/printing-hex-values-in-x86-assembly).

Answer (score 1):

The key to printing hexadecimal bytes is remembering that the ASCII code for a number is its value plus `0x30`. There are versions of this code that are far more optimized than this, but are harder to read and understand, so I'll give you the more readable version:

```
PrintHex:
;input: al = the byte you wish to print.
push ax

shr al,1
shr al,1
shr al,1
shr al,1     ;move the top 4 bits to the bottom.
call ShowHex
pop ax
and al,0Fh   ;now print the bottom 4 bits as ASCII.

;fallthrough is intentional - we want to run this code again and return.

ShowHex:
add al,30h       ;converts the digit to ASCII
cmp al,3Ah       ;if greater than A, we need letters A through F
jc noCorrectHex
    add al,7     ;3Ah becomes "A", 3Bh becomes "B", etc.
noCorrectHex:

mov dl,al
mov ah,2
int 21h      ;print
ret
```