# How to convert normal bytes to ascii in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, hex, ascii, real-mode

I am trying to write a function for my real mode operating system that will dump memory. I want the byte 0x0a to show up as '0A', 0xf3 to show up as 'F3' and so on and so forth. The code I wrote uses a table that consists of '0123456789ABCDEF', and uses the individual nibble as an offset to find the right character. First it saves the value, which is in `al`. Next it shifts `al` right by 4, removing the lower nibble and moving the higher nibble down. It then load the table into `di`, and zeros out `ah`. Next, it adds `ax` to `di` to find the offset. It then moves the value at `di` into al, and prints it. It then follows the same steps except that it then uses the low nibble instead of the high nibble. However, when I run it, it only prints out '33' repeatedly, instead of the actual hex numbers. Here is my code:

```
memdump:            
mov si, 0x7000      ;load si
loop:               
    mov al, [si]        ;put the value at si into al
    call printhex       ;call the hex printer
    inc si          ;increment si
    cmp si, 0x7CFF      ;are we done?
    je done         ;yes, return
    jmp loop        ;loop
printhex:           
    mov al, bl      ;save al
    shr al, 4       ;remove the lower nibble and move the higher nibble down
    mov di,hexbuffer    ;put the hexadecimal buffer in di
    xor ah, ah      ;remove everything from ah
    add di, ax      ;add the address to the buffer
    mov al, [di]        ;move the ascii char into al
    mov ah, 0x0E        ;teletype printing for int 0x10
    int 0x10        ;print the character
    mov bl, al      ;reload al
    shl al, 4       ;remove the high nibble
    shr al, 4       ;move the new high nibble down
    mov di, hexbuffer   ;reload the buffer
    xor ah, ah      ;zero out ah
    add di, ax      ;add the offset
    mov al, [di]        ;transfer the ascii char
    mov ah, 0x0E        ;teletype printing for int 0x10
    int 0x10        ;print the char
    mov al, ' '     ;now print a space
    int 0x10        ;print the space
    ret         ;return
done:               
    ret         ;return to kernel
    hexbuffer db '0123456789ABCDEF'
```

What is the problem with it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing Hexadecimal Digits with Assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853730/printing-hexadecimal-digits-with-assembly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that the `mov al, bl; save al` and the `mov bl, al ; reload al` have the operands reversed.

If you are already writing your so-called operating system, you should be familiar with a debugger so you can fix your own mistakes.

Comment: Such a simple mistake! Stupid me! I probably should have debugger, I never thought about it. I suppose my OS is somewhat of a side hobby.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at my example on this page for converting a 32 bit value in EAX to 8 hexadecimal ASCII bytes:
[Printing out a number in assembly language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922134/printing-out-a-number-in-assembly-language/22897576#22897576)