# Dividing in Assembler x86

Tags: assembly, x86

My college gave me a exercise:

*1. Create a new document in Jasmin*

*2. Use the AL-Register to to add 9 to 8.*

*3. Subtract 2.*

*4. Divide by 7.*

My solution is:

```
mov al,9
add al,8
sub al,2
```

But how do I divide by 7? I tried something like `div al,7` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`div` operation divides (unsigned) the value in the AX, DX:AX, or EDX:EAX registers (dividend) by the source operand (divisor) and stores the result in the AX (AH:AL), DX:AX, or EDX:EAX registers.

[source](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_72.html)

so, to divide value in al, you need to do:

```
mov ah, 0 # clean up ah, also you can do it before, like move ax, 9
mov bl, 7 # prepare divisor
div bl # al = ax / bl, ah = ax % bl
```

after that al will contain quotient and ah will contain remainder

Comment: How does `div` know, whether it should divide AX, DX:AX or EDX:EAX?

Comment: @S.Eberl depending on argument, bl, bx, ebx -> ax, dx:ax, edx:eax

Comment: So, if I divide by bl it automatically divides ax?

Comment: @S.Eberl yes, for any 8bit argument it will divide ax, for any 16bit argument - dx:ax

Comment: Thank you! One last question: Can I output ax? Or how can I see the value of ax?

Comment: @S.Eberl you can see it in any debugger or output it like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922134/printing-out-a-number-in-assembly-language

Answer (score 2):

There's a `DIV` instruction [which does division](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_72.html), but you'll need to put the dividend into `AX` (or one of its siblings) first.

Answer (score 2):

The [`div`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/DIV.html) and `idiv` instructions don't have forms that take an immediate.  They only take one explicit operand (register or memory), with the dividend being implicit in AX, or DX:AX, EDX:EAX, or RDX:RAX. 
 See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574914/8086-assembly-on-dosbox-bug-with-idiv-instruction/43575674#43575674) for how to use them.

But x86 in 16 and 32-bit mode does have an immediate-division instruction, and it's actually slightly faster than `div r/m8` on Intel CPUs before Skylake:  **[`aam 7`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/AAM.html) will divide AL by an immediate 7, placing the quotient in AH, remainder in AL.**  (https://agner.org/optimize/ says that on Haswell it has 1 cycle lower latency, and 1 cycle better throughput than `div r8`.  And it's 8 uops instead of 9.)

Note that it's different from **`mov cl, 7` / `div cl`**, which takes the whole of AX as the dividend, and places **quotient in AL, remainder in AH**.

**AAM is not available in 64-bit long mode**, removed along with the other less-useful legacy BCD instructions.  But if it saves uops overall (including `mov` an immediate to a register), it could be useful.  On Skylake, it costs 11 uops vs. 10 for `div r8`, and has 1c *worse* throughput, and same latency.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for only single digit numbers division.

```
.model small
.data
 msg1 db 'enter dividend:$'
 msg2 db 10,13,'enter divisor:$'
 result db 10,13,'result is:$'
 dividend db ?
 divisor db ?
.code
.startup
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov ah,9
lea dx,msg1
int 21h
mov ah,1
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov dividend ,al
mov ah,9
lea dx,msg2
int 21h
mov ah,1
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov divisor , al
mov al,dividend
mov bl,divisor
mov ah,0
div bl
mov ah,9
lea dx,result
int 21h
mov ah,2
add al,30h
mov dl,al
int 21h
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
end
```