# multiplying a number more than 3 give wrong answer in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, emu8086

[image: This is the output]

I try to write a multiply code from c to assembly from 1 to 50 like:

```
1 MUL 1
2 MUL 2
```

and so on but when its `4 MUL 4` doesn't give a right number it give me the character `@`.

I wrote it in assembly 8086 code can you help me to know where is the problem cause I am new at it

```
.MODEL SMALL
.DATA
Y DW 50 DUP (?) 
.CODE
MOV AX,@DATA
MOV DS,AX   
MOV WORD PTR SI,OFFSET Y
MOV Cx,1
L1:     
MOV Ax,Cx 
IMUL Ax  
ADD Ax,30H
MOV [SI],Ax
MOV Dx,[SI]
ADD SI,2         
MOV Ah,02H  
INT 21H 
INC Cx
CMP Cx,51
JE L2
JMP L1
L2:
.EXIT 
END
```

Comment: The statement in the title conflicts with the content. Does it fail at 3x3 or 4x4?

Comment: WHEN 4*4 IT GIVE A CHARACTER NOT NUMBER

Comment: 1) No need to shout. 2)If that is the case, clearly the required response is to correct the false statement in the title rather than repeat the question in a comment.

Comment: The fact that it outputs a character is important information that you should include in the question, not a comment.  You should also specify which character (clearly `@`). That information would confirm the veracity of my answer.

Comment: i edit it could you see it and thanks

Comment: The title still needs correcting.  What is hard to understand about that!?  I have in any case answered the question already.  If you need a solution, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922134/printing-out-a-number-in-assembly-language for example (not the accepted answer, but various solutions are presented that will suit).  Int21,2 outputs a single character. For multiple digit results you need to output a _string_ (int21,9), and convert the integer to a decimal string.

Comment: My apologies - I misread the title; it is fine.  I have fixed other formatting issues with the post.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be adding 30h to the result to translate the value to an ASCII digit character.  That wil clearly only work for single digit results 0 to 9.

It is not the multiplication that is in error, it is your output method that is flawed.  Outputting a human readable result to the console is the most complex part of this task by far.

Comment: IT DOESNT WORK I ADD TO THE RESULT

Comment: @a.f321 You appear to have a stuck caps key.  Stop shouting.  I know it does not work - this answer explains clearly why it does not work.  It does not provide a solution - with respect, you did not ask for a solution, only an indication of the cause.

Comment: iam sorry iam not shouting but i`ve tried to fix it and it don't be fixed

Comment: And as I pointed out, your question does not ask for a fix, only the cause.

Comment: can you correct my code ?

Comment: @A.F312 I am no x86 assembly expert, and certainly not obsolete 16bit/DOS assembly. It is just easy to see where the issue is with only the bare minimum of read-only ASM skills.  Besides your question asks _only_  "_help me to know where is the problem cause_" - you should perhaps ask a separate question about outputting an integer value to the DOS console, but clearly that would be a duplicate of the question I linked to in a previous comment.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244624/print-integer-to-console-in-x86-assembly

Comment: https://riptutorial.com/x86/example/26199/ms-dos--tasm-masm--function-to-print-a-16-bit-number-in-decimal

Comment: @A.F312: You asked basically the same question yesterday (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71444362/trynna-write-a-multiply-code-in-assembly-8086), which I closed as a duplicate of [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45904075), then you deleted your question.  That Q&A explains how to turn large integers into multi-digit ASCII strings.  Go read it instead of taking up more of other people's time asking something that's already been answered.